# How to throw an error message in C#?

Tags: c#, error-handling, subroutine

I would like to understand what is wrong with my code because it does not display an error message to the user. Thank you for your suggestions.

```
   public class Program
   {
      static void Main (string[] args)  {
      Console.WriteLine("Please, input some text");
      string name = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine(AskString(name));
      Console.ReadLine();        
    }

     public static string AskString(string greeting)
    {
        if (greeting == "")
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Parameter cannot be null");                
            Console.WriteLine("Text input failed in subroutine AskString");
        }

        return greeting;            
    }
```

Comment: You have to put `Console.WriteLine("Text input failed in subroutine AskString");`  before `throw new System.Exception("Parameter cannot be null");` since it leaves the if-scope as soon as you throw the exception. Meaning the program never reaches your error message.
Also, Alexei has a good point regarding null/whitespace checks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After throw the execution of application will be stop, so your message will not be appear.

change your code

```
 Console.WriteLine("Text input failed in subroutine AskString"); 
throw new System.Exception("Parameter cannot be null");
```

Also, when you throw new exception, it must be handle in another place. if you don't do that your application will be crash

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, `greeting == ""` returns false. Try [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) instead to ignore characters like CR or LF.

Answer (score 1):

You're trowing an exception that is not handled at any higher level in your application (so you won't see anything). The code after the throw will not be reached in any case because of the throw.